# Cannot enable vpclink for my vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc

I am trying to enable vpc link support in my account. So I followed what is mentioned here:

[vpc linlk support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-classiclink.html#classiclink-enable-dns-support)

and specifically this section:

[image]

But I cannot see it in my account when I try it:

[image]

Is it a bug or am I doing sth wrong?

Comment: Are **DNS Hostnames** and/or **DNS Resolution** marked as **yes** for this VPC?

Comment: @MrDuk Yes they are

Comment: You won't see this option in a region where your account does not have access to the EC2 Classic platform -- and newer accounts don't support EC2 Classic in any region.  The question prompts me to ask what problem you are trying to solve with this option, since it appears to be the case that you don't have any EC2 Classic resources in the region you're viewing.